# Как сделать свою сборку ExtJS ?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать свою сборку скрипта ExtJS ?
И если можно то как это сделать ?
Желательно на основе используемых в проекту классах, если это можно определить автоматически...

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу!  
Задача весьма актуальная, учитывая размер полной сжатой библиотеки...

Comment: Да, речь идет как раз о 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть специальная утилита, работающая из командной строки.

> Sencha Cmd is a cross-platform command line tool that provides many automated tasks around the full life-cycle of your applications, from generating a new project to deploying an application to production.

Перед компиляцией желательно собрать свой проект в правильную структуру. Если хоть где-то будет ошибка, работать будет плохо (у нас подхватывало не все пространства имён). Компилятору надо указать, где лежат файлы самого фреймворка, дополнительных компонентов и собственно приложения. Также, там указывается копмрессия (там есть параметр closure, он выполняет упаковку javascript-кода с помощью Google Closure Compiler, можно и другие средства вызывать). Также, при компиляции осуществляется преобразование SCSS в CSS.

На сайте есть достаточно подробная документация по использованию SDK. Еще, обратите внимание, что в с помощью SDK можно сгенерировать достаточно удобный шаблон проекта, выполненный по всем рекомендациям Extjs.

[Официальное руководство](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command)

Comment: Сложно написано...  
С моим знанием английского или онлайновыми переводчиками сложно все разобраться...  
Нет ли перевода статьи?